# Display jsonArray in angular js table format

Tags: angularjs, arrays, dynamic

I am getting response data as:

```
array=[{"job id":"1",
        "level 1":"er",
        "level 2":"ED",
        "level 3":"MT",
        "status":"mt"
       },
      {"job id":"2",
       "level 1":"ear",
       "level 2":"ED",
       "level 3":"MT",
       "status":"mt"}
     ]
```

In above array there are two records retrieved from database and it may vary accordingly.

And I want to represent in Table format and column must be job id, level 1, level 2 etc and values 1, ed, etc as  in angular JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `(key,value)` in `ng-repeat`

```js
var app=angular.module('app',[])
app.controller("Ctrl",function($scope,$filter){
   $scope.array=[
          {"job id":"1","level 1":"er","level 2":"ED","level 3":"MT","status":"mt"},
          {"job id":"2","level 1":"ear","level 2":"ED","level 3":"MT","status":"mt"}
     ]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller=" Ctrl">
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in array" ng-if="$last">
         <td ng-repeat="(key,v) in value">{{key}}</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
       <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in array">
         <td ng-repeat="(key,v) in value">{{v}}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, thanks I got the values in my row but I want key as column name dynamically.  In my application I had divided response in to arrays like $scope.Columns which contains key values like 0,1 and $scope.Rows contains [  {"job id":"1","level 1":"er","level 2":"ED","level 3":"MT","status":"mt"}, {"job id":"2","level 1":"ear","level 2":"ED","level 3":"MT","status":"mt"}]  So from your answer I had retrieved row values for my table by using (key,value) in Rows . So please tell how to display column names as job id ,level 1 ,level 2 etc dynamically.

Comment: Hi, IS there another way to get the values because in the above solution we are providing keys statically.

Comment: Thanks its working . Can you explain this ng-if="$last" ??

Comment: it is for create one row one columns.